# Create new arrays from Multidimensional array rows in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, row

```
$multidimensionalArray = [[false,true,false], 
 [false,false,true], 
 [true,false,false], 
 [false,true,true]];
```

I know there is array_column function if I want to create new arrays from multidimensional array's columns. But I want to create new arrays from every row. What is the **easiest way** for this?

Result will be like this:

```
$array1 = [false,true,false];
$array2 = [false,false,true];
$array3 = [true,false,false];
$array4 = [false,true,true];
```

Comment: if you know that  the array always contains 4 rows: `list($ar1, $ar2, $ar3, $ar4) = $multidimensionalArray;`

Answer (score 2):

```
extract($multidimensionalArray, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'array');
```

You will get:

```
$array_0 = [false,true,false];
$array_1 = [false,false,true];
$array_2 = [true,false,false];
$array_3 = [false,true,true];
```

Comment: Great! I was looking for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php

$multidimensionalArray = [[false,true,false], 
 [false,false,true], 
 [true,false,false], 
 [false,true,true]];


for($i = 1; $i < count($multidimensionalArray); $i++){
    ${'array' . $i} = $multidimensionalArray[$i];
}

var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
var_dump($array3);
var_dump($array4);
```

Comment: Thank u... only I changed $i starting point... for ($i = 0; $i < count($multidimensionalArray); $i++) {
        ${'array' . ($i+1)} = $multidimensionalArray[$i];
    }